# Why is my NodeJS app inserting rows twice at mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, row, mqtt

I have a NodeJS app which is connected to a Mosquitto server, and it logs every single message sent to the MQTT server (only if the SN of the device exists in the DB).

But for somehow reason at the moment of executing the query to insert a new row, it  inserts twice the same row, and i still cant figure out why.

First here is a listener for new messages received at the mqtt broker

```
this.client.on('message', (topic, message) =\> {
const dato = { topic, message: message.toString() };
console.log(`Message received: ${JSON.stringify(dato)}`);
this.messageReceivedViewModel.handleMessage(dato);
> });
```

Then it checks if the device already exists in the db

```
handleMessage(dato) {     
   this.dato = new Data(dato.topic, dato.message);     
   this.existingDeviceViewModel.checkDevice(dato);   
}
```

```
async checkDevice(dato) {
    console.log('SN: ', dato.message.split(',')[0].trim())

    const device = await this.dataRepository.findDevice(dato.message.split(',')[0].trim());

    if (device.length != 0) {
      console.log('valor de device: ', device);
      await this.activityLogViewModel.logActivity(dato);
    } else {
      console.error(`Device with SN ${dato.message.split(',')[0].trim()} not found`);
    }
  }
```

```
async findDevice(sn) {
if (this.pool === null) {
console.error('Database pool not established');
return;
>     }
await this.init();
const [rows, fields] = await this.pool.execute('SELECT * FROM `device` WHERE `serial_number` = ?', [sn]);

return rows;
>   }
```

Once the app confirmed that device is registered at the DB , it executes the query

```
    async logActivity(dato) {
        console.log(dato.message);
        const log = {
          date_at: new Date(),
          action_performed: dato.message.split(',')[1].trim(),
          topic_received: dato.topic,
          message: dato.message,
        };
        try {
          console.log('About to call insertLog');
          await this.dataRepository.insertLog(log);
          console.log('Finished calling insertLog');
          console.log(`1 row inserted successfully`);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    }
```

```
async init() {
    try {
      this.pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: process.env.DBHOST,
        user: process.env.DBUSER,
        password: process.env.DBPASS,
        database: process.env.DBNAME,
        waitForConnections: true,
        connectionLimit: 1,
        queueLimit: 1
      });
      console.log('Database pool established successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error  creating database pool: ', error);
    }
  }

  async insertLog(log) {

    await this.init();
    if (this.pool === null) {
      console.error('Database connection not established');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Executing insertLog');
    const {  date_at, action_performed, topic_received, message} = log;
    const rows = await this.pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`triggered_at`, `action_performed`, `topic_received`, `message`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
      [date_at, action_performed, topic_received, message]
    );
    console.log('Completed insertLog operation: ', rows);
  }
```

The query seems to execute just once, because the console logs appears just once at the console, also the info returned by the query execution says "affectedRows:1"

[image]

> 19091419, Cerrar Puerta4 About to call insertLog Database pool
> established successfully Executing insertLog Completed insertLog
> operation:  [   ResultSetHeader {

> ```
> fieldCount: 0,
> affectedRows: 1,
> insertId: 33,
> info: '',
> serverStatus: 2,
> warningStatus: 0   },
> ```
>
> undefined ]
> Finished calling insertLog   1 row inserted successfully

But as you can see, all the rows are duplicated

[image]

Anyone knows why are the rows inserting twice?

Comment: where is the code that executes insertLog function?

Comment: Are you 100% sure there isn't 2 copies of this code running? MQTT messages will be delivered to ALL clients that are subscribed to the topic.

Comment: @mikrowdev Its on the 5th code block.  I put all my code on the order it is executed, as you can see, first the message event listener executes the method handleMessage, which then executes  the method "checkDevice".  In the checkDevice method, once the app confirmed the Device already exists in DB it executes logActivity which executes insertLog.

Sorry i completely forgot to add that code block.

Comment: @hardillb how can i make sure im executing it just once?
im executing my app using "npm start" in console.
Here is my start script in the package.json file:
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  }

Comment: @hardillb you were right.
I didnt notice that there was another instance of my app running in background i dont even know how that happened, thank you my dear, u saved my life.